# Getting ClassCastException while using list of enum values defined in application properties of Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have put a list of enum String values in application.properties as following:

```
my.enumValues = enumValu1,enumValue2
```

Now in one of the component, I am injecting it as follows:

```
@Value("${my.enumValues}")
List<MyEnum> myEnumList;
```

Now, while iterating over this list inside code, I am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class MyEnum (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; MyEnum is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I am not getting any clue regarding how to fix it. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the datatype of list is "MyEnum". It should be String.

```
@Value("${my.enumValues}")
List<String> myEnumList;
```

OR

Accept the values as one String and then split it by comma.
Try something like

```
@Value("${my.enumValues}")
private String myEnums;

final List<String> enums= Arrays.asList(myEnums.split(","));
```